# Why goodness of fit via deviance and chisq is poor for poisson regression (glm)?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, poisson-regression, deviance

Simulate a poisson model:

```
set.seed(1)
predictor <- rnorm(100000, 2.5, 0.5)
# describe(predictor)
lam <- 0.98 * predictor
# describe(lam)

rp <- function(lambda){rpois(1, lambda)}
vrp <- Vectorize(rp)

response <- vrp(lam)
# describe(response)

fit <- glm(response ~ 1, offset=log(predictor), family="poisson")
summary(fit)
```

Regression:

```
Call:
glm(formula = response ~ 1, family = "poisson", offset = log(predictor))

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.8188  -0.8334  -0.1146   0.5777   4.3871  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.017707   0.002018  -8.773   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 111501  on 99999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 111501  on 99999  degrees of freedom
AIC: 361334

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

> pchisq(111501, 99999)
[1] 1
```

This above should be an exact fit, I don't get why `pchisq` is giving me so extreme number.

Reference link: [When someone says residual deviance/df should ~ 1 for a Poisson model, how approximate is approximate?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37732/when-someone-says-residual-deviance-df-should-1-for-a-poisson-model-how-appro)

#### Update

I found this http://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/stat/Regression-GLM/GLM2-SigTests/

And it suggests to use pearson's residual instead of deviance to perform a goodness of fit... and it works much better.

```
ssr <- sum(residuals(fit, type="pearson")^2)
pchisq(ssr, 99999)
```

Comment: Interesting question. A couple of comments -- (1) `rpois` will generate from a vector of lambdas as is, you don't need to go through all that trouble to get it to do that; (2) Why do you say the fit should be exact? The model should be correct, but that's not the same as the fit being 'exact', unless you define 'exact' in a somewhat different way to its usual meaning.

Comment: @Glen_b (1) Really? Once in an interview I thought `rpois` would vectorize lambdas, then I failed...that hurt me....I will try it again. (2) by "exact" I mean the model should be correct. So normally I expect the stats be within 0.05 to 0.95 on a few trials with different seeds.

Comment: Yes really. Just *try* it for goodness sake: `rpois(3,lambda=c(3,100,4))`. If you failed the interview *for correctly stating the behaviour of rpois*, *you don't want to work there*. Mind you, if you just accept what people tell you when you can easily check, you are going to be dealing with the consequences of other people's mistakes your whole life.